# How to estimate the contribution of an individual to a software project?

Tags: software-estimation

I work on a software project and would like to estimate the percentage out of the total contribution that I have put in the development of the software. Is there some tool doing this? Such a tool can be useful for appraisals or negotiations, for example. After all, we work for money (yes, not only money, put the point remains). I think there is enough hand-waving for the most important things.

The estimation is very subjective (at least to me now) but I do not know of any tool that provides even a subjective estimate. I know of Sloccount that spells out the total effort using the lines of code but not on per-developer basis.

My idea of an ideal tool for this purpose would:

- measure the complexity of the code (more complex is more effort, but more effort is not necessarily more contribution)
- measure the decomposibility/flexibility of the software (more decomposable is better)
- how much library code is used -- using library code speeds up the development process, increases the associated risk and requires the developer to know from before or learn about the library.
- be intelligent enough to differentiate between "who wrote the code", "who copied the code" and "who indented the code".

It is difficult to differentiate between the complexity in the implementation and the intrinsic complexity of the problem. Perhaps a comparison can be made with an equivalent open source counterpart if there is, or for each submodule separately.

If there is no such tool, is there no merit in having such a tool? Or do you believe in "I do work, I do not measure"? It takes time after all. Perhaps the project manager should do this estimation continuously, say, weekly. Are there any standards? Yes, standardization is difficult because every project has different goals, but perhaps that should mean there should be multiple standards, not no standards at all. This looks similar to the how a company is valued in the market.

**Update**: after seeing a few initial answers: It does not make sense to imagine a tool that just outputs the percentages. Are there tools that can help humans (particularly managers) in making better decisions? Or what is the sufficient statistic for making better decisions? Are these statistics available?

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt there is any reliable trustworthy way of measuring individual's contribution to the solution. Sometimes rewriting some complicated legacy code that results in less lines of code, less complicated solution (smaller cyclomatic complexity etc.) can be seen as a quite significant contribution, while in other cases deleting valuable code covering edge cases that results in the same statistics (less lines of code, smaller CC etc.) is definitely something bad. It all comes down to people, trust and cooperation, individualism in the team is almost always wrong and I would rather avoid it and especially not use it as a motivation factor.

Comment: Individualism in the team is wrong when the team is small and the individuals gel well. In large teams or when the individuals do not identify well with the team, the individual wins. Yes, it makes sense for a manager to not use "points" for motivation, but as a private information.

Comment: In the case of "deleting valuable code" this will be manifested in an increased bug count. Of course, detecting which change led to a bug is a challenging problem in itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is a research topic on its own. There are several tools that have tried to define metrics like **[code ownership](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki$?CodeOwnership)**. There are other approaches which tackle other aspect of collaborative development, for instance the **[trustability](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Gysi10a.pdf)** we can have in the code.

There has been also several studies that tried to use the information from **bug trackers**. For instance, to identify the developer that is the more likely to introduce bugs. But it's hard to be objective (A brilliant developer that is assigned the most critical part of the system, will still be more likely to introduce critical bugs).

It's actually hard to **monetize** the development tasks. What is the cost of a bug? What is the gain of refactoring? That would be however one way to estimate the contribution of a developer.

The last cool tool I saw of this kind was the [Game Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/The+Continuous+Integration+Game+plugin) for Hudson **continuous integration** system. A score is assigned to each developer according their actions

- -10 if they break the build
- -1 for breaking a test
- +1 for fixing a test
- etc.

That's again a way to somehow assess the contribution of the developer.

All in all, I do feel like what you are asking for exist, but is still very immature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get a tool to evaluate your share of the project. Measuring lines of source is all very well, but what of the quality of that source? You wouldn't want someone taking the credit for 200 lines of source if the job could have been easiy done in 20...

Also, thinking of my employer for a moment, a lot of people contribute to the project in ways other than code. Immediate examples I can think of would be Project Managers and Testers - both of whom are essential, both of whom rightly deserve some credit.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I could imagine would be a voting system. I have absolutely no idea, if that would work in your team or anywhere - but I'm sure, that you will need humans for any realistic estimation of code quality.

Answer (score 0):

In Stroustrup's Book on C++ I've read once "Don't try to solve social problems with technical means".

Thinking progmatically, the attitude and the ability of a programmer could be very quickly estimated by making a code-review together and having a talk on relevant topics.

[image]

Thinking as an IT-enthusiast and as a control-freak, this shouldn't be very hard, to implement a teachable machine-learning software, which uses version-cotrol, bug-database, etc and greates real-time performanced data for each contributor. E.g. R, KNIME or WEKA  could be used for this.